# How to iterate over string objects in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to start the Riiid Answer Correctness Prediction, and I got stuck in a very early phrase.

I would need to iterate over 'tags' column and count occurrences of each tag.
[image]

How do I extract, explode or change 'tags' values so that I could use value_counts() or apply(eval)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually achieve this with one line using [`pd.Series.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) and [`pd.Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html).

```
df.tags.str.split().explode().value_counts()

131    5
162    4
38     2
36     1
29     1
81     1
149    1
5      1
51     1
92     1
101    1
```